# Maybe a dumb one, but is passing an empty http get parameter the same as passing none at all?

Tags: http, get

The title basically sums it up, but to specify, would

www.stackoverflow.com?get=

be the same as

www.stackoverflow.com

Assuming serverside is PHP or Java...

Comment: This depends on what language and framework you're using, please [edit] your question to provide this data. Also, it's not "HTML" (Which is a Language) but HTTP (which is a Protocol).

Comment: This question is entirely context-sensitive and based on how the server-side code for that page is set up to handle query strings (if it is).